# Powershell : Delete and replace Line in text File between 2 Line contain a specific String

Tags: powershell

i know how to replace line using Ps but in my case is quite different. using a Powershell Script,  i need to delete all lines between 2 specific Line and replace it by another text.

```
Text file contain n Line
.
.
.
elementLIST_PROPERTY
    Computer
    Hard Drive
    DVD ROM
    Memory
ElementFinList_Property
.
.
.
```

Result

```
.
.
.
elementLIST_PROPERTY
    Camera
    Objectif
    Zoom
ElementFinList_Property
.
.
.
```

thanks in advance

so the big deal how to delete and insert new text betwwen 2 exact Line

Comment: how will you define which lines you want the text to be replaced on? Where is the replacement text coming from?

Comment: @SEarle1986 i want to replace the text between the two delimeter "elementLIST_PROPERTY" and "ElementFinList_Property" like the example